# Estoy haciendo un menu drawer con flutter, pero quiero agregar listas desplegables

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, menu

```
drawer: Drawer{
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.greenAccent, Colors.green])),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    elevation: 8,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'images/logo.png',
                        width: 80,
                        height: 80,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.5),
                    child: Text('Main Drawer'),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: const Text(
                      "pagina.com",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          color: Colors.black45),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      launch("https://www.paginaweb.com");
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Import'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              selected: (0 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onselectItem(0);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Gallery'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.photo),
              selected: (1 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onselectItem(1);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),`
```

hice un main Drawer siguiendo un tutorial.
en ves de los "ListTile" quiero poner las listas desplegables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba a analizar el siguiente código.

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Expansion Title"),
        children: <Widget>[Text("children 1"), Text("children 2")],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Creo que te refieres a esto.

Esta pregunta ya ha sido resuelta en otro post, te dejo el enlace por si quieres consultarlo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706739/flutter-how-to-add-a-expandable-menu-item-inside-navigation-drawer

Comment: Gracias, creo que me sirve. el problema es que quiero que al presionar los "children" te manden a esa seccion. ¿sabes como  puedo detectar el click?.

Comment: Podrías usar un GestureDetector https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: Exactamente con el GestureDetector puedes detectar los clicks de distintas maneras. Ya sea un solo click, doble click, click largo, etc. Espero que te sirvan las respuestas dadas.

Comment: gracias, me ayudó